# A member with the name 'Id' already exists on `Model`. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, mapping

I have DTO with next structure :

```
public class DTO
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   [JsonProperty("Id")]
   public int ServerId {get;set;}
}
```

From server I receive json from next model :

```
public class ServerModel
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

I want to Deserialize json from ServerModel into DTO with rule `=>` `Id` from server map to `ServerId` property. But currently I get error :

> A member with the name 'Id' already exists on `DTO`. Use the
>   JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.

Can I somehow resolve this? Or I just can change my ServerModel to match what I have on client (`DTO`) ?

Comment: (Minimal experience in C# here, so this is all a guess) Your DTO has an `Id` field which is most likely getting the default json identifier of `Id`, and then you are specifying that `ServerId` should be identified as `Id` as well in the json. You could either specify a `[JsonProperty('anotherName')]` for `Id` or ignore it when serializing/deserializing.

Comment: @CollinD, thanks. I think it's good idea

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you simply don't want to read any JSON values into `DTO.Id`, you should apply [`[JsonIgnore]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) to it:

```
public class DTO
{
   [JsonIgnore]
   public int Id {get;set;}
   [JsonProperty("Id")]
   public int ServerId {get;set;}
}
```

Having done so, upon deserializing the following JSON: `{"Id" : 101}`, `DTO.ServerId` will get the value of `101` while `DTO.Id` will not be set.

As it is you're specifying a JSON data contract that maps two different c# properties to a JSON property named `"Id"`.  This is not allowed by Json.NET, since such a contract could not be serialized.